# What the best way protecting REST service? Should it be a part of site?

Tags: rest, architecture, model, system, subdomain

I have started to work in a new company. We have rest service (XML exchange with external system) and have web site. REST service work on subdomain, for example `rest.mycompany.com`. Company site is `mycompany.com`. Site and rest work like that 
REST -> DB <-SITE. This means that REST is not a part of site. It's an independent system. REST and site work with one database and use 90% same code (model, mapper etc). The problem for me is double coding and I wonder why it can't be a part of site (Import export controller, XML parser and one logger system)? On the other hand, it may be better to have different systems in terms of security and highloading for each subdomain...separated traffic for each subdomain?

Comment: any reason not to get site's data from the REST service?

Comment: Most site data get from Rest.

Comment: if your site is getting its data from the service, yet it still repeating 90% of the service's code, then you might be doing it wrong, i would suggest to look into that first,

p.s.: im not an expert on this, but i think repeating your code is rarely a good thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Site and rest work like that REST -> DB <-SITE. This means that REST is not a part of site. It's an independent system. REST and site work with one database and use 90% same code (model, mapper etc).

That's a big problem. Especially since one system might generate a bug (inconsistent data) which only shows in the other system. Quite hard to debug.

> The problem for me is double coding and I wonder why it can't be a part of site (Import export controller, XML parser and one logger system)?

The REST service and the website are just UI layers. The actual business logic should be moved to a third project (class library / module / lib) which both UI layer uses.

> On the other hand, it may be better to have different systems in terms of security and highloading for each subdomain...separated traffic for each subdomain?

I would stick with different sites. Not for performance but since they have distinct responsibilities.